# How do I shorten my program explained in my body?

Tags: python

I am making a simple python project for encrypting messages. Before I share what I want to shorten here is the link to my code for decrypting a message (that I need help with):
https://www.sendspace.com/file/jji74r

My problem is I don't know how to read the message without having to have 25 lines of code, this program tests for 25 characters of encrypted message so if I want to test 30 characters of encrypted text I need 5 more lines of code. Is there any method of decreasing the size of any part of my program?

Comment: Could you share an example? That would help

Comment: Please post your code here. There are nice formatting options for posting code built into the site.

Comment: According to this site's [mre] page, "`DO NOT use images of code`"

Comment: @Nv7 The example of the code i need to shorten is in the sendspace link, I used the link because the code was to large for the body.

Comment: @Jacobr365 Ok next time I will make sure to post my code here, I am sorry this is my first post here.

Comment: Could you provide some example input? I think I know how to do this, but I need some input to test it on

Comment: @Nv7 here is example input:                                        Please input your BEM key: 711161098909491093652476466957397341920383143007333958442051743434090721137268
please input the message you wish to decrypt (up to 26 characters): 711161098
abc

Comment: I posted an answer, see if it works. I can also give you help over email  or discord if you don't fully understand, I just didn't want a really long answer

Comment: @Nv7 I don't fully understand, i'm a little busy atm so at 3pm est I will be available if u are able to help on discord at that time. my discord is Shakypro#5749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with some nested loops -

```py
INCREMENT = 3
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
BEM_LENGTH = 25

#data needed from user to decrypt a message encrypted via BEM
BEM = input("Please input your BEM key: ")
message = input("please input the message you wish to decrypt (up to 26 characters): ")

# processing
for i in range(0, len(message)//INCREMENT):
    mess = message[(i*INCREMENT):(i+1)*INCREMENT]
    for j in range(0, BEM_LENGTH):
        bem = BEM[(j*INCREMENT):(j+1)*INCREMENT]
        if mess == bem:
            print(ALPHABET[j], end="")
print()
```

I noticed that the change in the values was always 3, so the INCREMENT I set to 3.
I also needed the alphabet. I put in a BEM_LENGTH constant so that you can easily change it.

After that, I got the input.

Then, I looped through the message, with increments of 3 like you had hardcoded in. Then, I looped through the BEM key and compared it, similar to your if statements. Then, if they were matching, I printed the right character of the alphabet. If you need more help I could email you or chat on discord if you need some help!

I could do this in around 4 lines, using list comprehension, but it would be very difficult to read. This is the most readable, clean way of doing it.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answers your question, could you please mark it as correct? (press the check mark below the downvote button). I would also appreciate it if you could upvote it!

Comment: BTW, instead of defining `ALPHABET` manually you could `import string` and then use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase).

Comment: Wow, thats useful! The only thing is that for punctuation, etc you might need a different alphabet (including punctuation, special characters, etc.) But i do need to check out all the string constants